# ErrorActionPreference=stop stops all scripts stack

Tags: powershell

Consider the following:

```
// Calling-Script.ps1
Write-Output "Calling script"
./Failing-Script.ps1
Write-Output "Calling script again"

// Failing-Script.ps1
Write-Output "Failing script"
$ErrorActionPreference="stop"
Copy-Item invalid_file invalid_directory
Write-Output "Failing script again"

// output
Calling script
Failing script
```

Notice that `Calling script again` didn't show up. First I thought that somehow the change of `ErrorActionPreference` in `Failing-Script.ps1` affected the one in `Calling-Script.ps1`, but I checked it and it doesn't:

```
// Calling-Script.ps1
Write-Output "Calling script"
$ErrorActionPreference
./Failing-Script.ps1
Write-Output "Calling script again"
$ErrorActionPreference

// Failing-Script.ps1
Write-Output "Failing script"
$ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference="stop"
#Copy-Item invalid_file invalid_directory

Write-Output "Failing script again"
$ErrorActionPreference

// output
Calling script
Continue
Failing script
Continue
Failing script again
stop
Calling script again
Continue
```

The question is: Why is the execution of `Calling-Script.ps1` stops? Does this make sense? is it documented?

Comment: The point of `ErrorActionPreference` set to `Stop` is to stop execution when a non-terminating error happens. Typically, this would be for debugging or if you want to do error handling like through `try {} catch {}`. The `copy-item` command would throw a non-terminating error in this case but instead becomes terminating when you set the value to `Stop`.

Comment: I pretty much know all that. The question was more about: why is the `Calling-Script.ps1` execution stops also.

Comment: Because a terminating error causes an exception, which goes up in the callstack until catched. If not catched, it terminates the session.

Comment: Try this: `try { ./Failing-Script.ps1 } catch { "Catched error!" }`